# Can't shutdown/restart linux

Tags: restart

This started yesterday, I'm dual booting win7 and Ubuntu but when I'm shutting down/restarting Ubuntu to switch OS I only get to the log-out screen.
I can turn the computer off with the power button but I would like to be able to do it the normal way.

Thanks in advance //Oskar

Comment: can you open a terminal and type `sudo reboot` or `sudo shutdown now`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below link in that very first question might solve your problem

http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/ubuntu-12-04-most-common-problems-and-solutions/

Also mention which ubuntu version you are using?